# How to Import/require a Browserify compiled file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, browserify, require

I like import psd.js in my Electron/NodeJS Application.

The normal way, `npm i psd` and `require('psd')` does not work for me, because then psd.js runs in NodeMode. Not in the Browser-Mode. I have to require the dist/psd.js directly, to get the BrowserMode. 
(Details in the github issue)

The Browser Version of dist/psd.js is already compiled with Browserify. Because of that its not a module which I can require with Node.

Has someone a solution for that with which i don't have to manipulate the psd.js file?

---

psd.js issue: https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/issues/59

The psd.js example to that, which won't work for me, because the require is from browserify and not from NodeJS:
https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/blob/master/examples/browser/image.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/psd.min.js"></script>
var PSD = require('psd');
```

---

The browserified js file: https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/blob/master/dist/psd.js

If I replace the `require=......` with `module.exports=` i can require that as usual

Comment: It looks like you just need to install as an NPM package? https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js#nodejs-example

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the module via npm.

The script tag is not necessary.  Once the package has been installed using npm you can require it in your index.html file with:

```
var psd = require('psd');
```

I am new to electron, and that's what I did when I included a node module in my index.html file.  I am not sure how electron does it, it seems strange to require a node module in the browser (index.html) but it works.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that. Normally you are right. But in this case I have to load the specific file, to run psd.js in BrowserMode. Details in my github issue: https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/issues/59